# Margin-top doesn't work after img element

Tags: html, css

why is it happen?

```
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2FCIU0MAB5Op7RAt-5u576obOi-9JKtseSgYJDMdhAc04mKoS"
 style="width:200px; height: 200px;"></img>

<span style="margin-top: 300px;">my text</span>
```

this is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8sxFT/1/

I know I can add `display: block` to the span and then `margin-top` will work.

but why isn't it working now? I closed the `img` element..

any help appreciated!

Comment: Images are inline so you would have to set the image to `display:block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: thank you, but the inline is not set only for the img element? so I closed the img element..

Comment: If you use a p tag instead of a span tag it will work better. As @Paulie_D said images are inline and so are spans, which is why it's not working.

Comment: Also, just so you know the proper way to close an img tag is <img /> not <img></img>. However, either way will work, just fyi.

Comment: yes, I know it but I prefer not to use it because I had the next case:
div element and inside of the div element I want to add another things.. because I used: <div /><span>1</span><span>2</span>

it didn't know where to close the div element. so I prefer to do it by myself.. thank you for your comment.. if you want, answer me as an answer and I will mark it..

Comment: also, closing <img> is not a requirement in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span element is inline element not a block element. So they ignore vertical margin value.

Solution is you can make the span element `display:inline-block;` Now you can use margin property.

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sxFT/3/)</kbd>

```
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2FCIU0MAB5Op7RAt-5u576obOi-9JKtseSgYJDMdhAc04mKoS" style="width:200px; height: 200px;"></img>
<br />
<span style="margin-top: 300px;display:inline-block;">my text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are forgetting to  use the float:leeft or right try it
 
`<img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2FCIU0MAB5Op7RAt-5u576obOi-9JKtseSgYJDMdhAc04mKoS' style="float:left;width:200px; height: 200px;">`

`<span style="float:left;margin-top: 300px;">my text</span>`

 you  don't  need to  close the img tag as you  did < /img>